# Detect x & y touch event in WP7 screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, touch

I am really need help with return the coordinates x and y in the WP7 screen.
this code help me to move an rectangle in the screen with showing the start(x&y), delta(x,y) and end(x,y) :

```
TransformGroup transformG;
    TranslateTransform translation;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ManipulationDelta += new EventHandler<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(MainPage_ManipulationDelta);
        transformG = new TransformGroup();
        translation = new TranslateTransform();
        transformG.Children.Add(translation);
        rectangle.RenderTransform = transformG;
    }

    void MainPage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        startX.Text =e.ManipulationOrigin.X.ToString();
        startY.Text = e.ManipulationOrigin.Y.ToString();
        DeltaX.Text = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X.ToString();
        DeltaY.Text = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y.ToString();
        translation.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        translation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        EndX.Text =Convert.ToString(translation.X);
        EndY.Text = Convert.ToString(translation.Y);
    }
```

I just want to do something like that but without move anything, just tap in the screen and know the start and the end with delta (difference).
I use silverlight

Comment: what if u remove  rectangle.RenderTransform = transformG; than the rectangle should stay on the same play shouldn't it?

Comment: I added it as answer pls mark it :)

Comment: Btw you can remove translation and transformG cuz they do nothing from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should remove  rectangle.RenderTransform = transformG; than the rectangle should stay on the same place.